# ¿Extraer datos de una web externa con JQUERY Y LARAVEL? [CORS]

Tags: jquery, laravel

estaba haciendo un mini proyecto para poder extraer parte del texto de una web externa, me he estado informando sobre el tema y por lo visto esto se llama CORS, he intentado implementarlo pero no me acaba de funcionar. Lo estoy haciendo mediante ajax con jquery, y he leido en varios sitios que hay usar como datatype jsonp o xml, y en su defecto añadir una cabecera tal que asi

```
headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"},
```

Esto es lo que tengo.
MI VISTA

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header" >{{$titulo}}</h1>

    {!! Form::open(['url' => '/lyrics', 'method' => 'POST','class' =>'form-horizontal']) !!}


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            {!! Form::hidden('taginicial', $tags['taginicial'] ) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('tagfinal', $tags['tagfinal']) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('pagina', $tags['pagina'] ) !!}
            {!! Form::label('', 'Interprete', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::text('interprete', 'Lorem ipsum.', ['disabled' => 'disabled','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            {!! Form::label('', 'Texto de la cancion', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('letra_cancion', 'Lorem ipsum dolor.', ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'textareacancion']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group" >
            {!! Form::submit('Inserta en base de datos', ['class' => 'form-control btn btn-info','id' => 'obtenletra']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>  

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

MI FUNCION AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var taginicial = $('input[name="taginicial"]').val();
    var tagfinal = $('input[name="tagfinal"]').val();
    var pagina = $('input[name="pagina"]').val();
    console.log(taginicial);
    console.log(tagfinal);
    console.log(pagina);
        $.ajax({
            url: pagina,
            crossDomain:true,
            headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {param1: 'value1'},
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });


});
```

Si en esta funcion omito las cabeceras me sale este error

```
Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').
```

Si no las omito y el tipo de datos lo pongo en xml, jsonp o incluso omito el tipo de datos el resultado es este

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

He probado sitios diferentes y he comprobado en sus cabeceras que el "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" esta asi,
¿Que me falla?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices la libreria guzzle/client

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

luego de instalarla miras la documentacion:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html

este seria su uso para obtener el html de la pagina que desees:

`$response = $client->request('GET',$url)->getBody();`

puedes crear un controlador que obtenga el html de la pagina y con jquery haces un llamado a ese controlador.

Al ser el controlador de tu propia aplicacion no te genera el problema de permisos.

Si necesitas manejar el html obtenido de la pagina en laravel puedes utilizar la libreria dom crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante aclarar porqué estás experimentando este error.

CORS, por sus siglas en inglés `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` es un mecanismo de seguridad que indica a los navegadores web no consumir APIs desde orígenes no autorizados.

Esto significa que si `https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing` no ha autorizado que a dominio actual ( http://127.0.0.1 por ejemplo ) consumir sus recursos, el navegador web se negará a acceder a ellos.

Como ya sabrás, esta autorización se da por medio de cabeceras HTTP, más específicamente la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, la cual puede contener un dominio en específico, o un comodín `*`.

Una posible solución sería hacer un request desde un servidor. Ya sea con alguna herramienta como `cURL` o desde algún lenguaje de programación, como ya proponían en otra respuesta.